# Python script works in current directory but not when one is specified

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to just print the content is work in other locations as well.

But when I want files to show their size as well, it only works in the current path.

```
import os
import sys

#check if a path is provided
#else use the current loction
arg_list = len(sys.argv) -1

if arg_list != 1:
    path = '.' 
elif arg_list == 1:
    path = sys.argv[1]

#list the files and directorys
#if it is a file also show it's size
catalog = os.listdir(path)

for item in catalog:
    #just print() here works also for other directories
    if os.path.isdir(item):
        print(f'    {item}')

    elif os.path.isfile(item):
        size = os.path.getsize(item)
        print(f'{size} {item}')
```

Comment: What happens to the file size display for other directories?

Answer (score 1):

This instruction: `catalog = os.listdir(path)` return the list of the files/folders inside the given directory without their full path, just the name.

So when you try to change folder `os.path.isdir` and  `os.path.isfile` don't find the reference to that file.

You should correct your script in this way:

```py
import os
import sys

#check if a path is provided
#else use the current loction
arg_list = len(sys.argv) -1

if arg_list != 1:
    path = '.' 
elif arg_list == 1:
    path = sys.argv[1]

#list the files and directorys
#if it is a file also show it's size
catalog = os.listdir(path)

for item in catalog:
    file = os.path.join(path, item) # <== Here you set the correct name with the full path for the file
    #just print() here works also for other directories
    if os.path.isdir(file):  # <== then change the reference here
        print(f'    {item}')

    elif os.path.isfile(file):  # <== here 
        size = os.path.getsize(file)  # <== and finally here
        print(f'{size} {item}')
```

Comment: `os.path.join()` rather than +'\'+ would be better.